# only select count value if total row count is equal to row count with special ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, loops, ssis

I need to select the the total number of rows with a certain ID **IF** it equals the total max rows in table.

I am using variables in this example, but I would like to do it with only  **one select statement**

```
DECLARE @a int, @b int

--total with special field (redcar = yes)
SELECT @a = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.car WHERE redcar = 'yes') 

-- max total of table
SELECT @b = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.car) 

IF(@a = @b)
BEGIN
SELECT @a
END
```

EXAMPLE
dbo.car

```
id  redcar
1    yes
2    
3    yes
4
5
6
```

The output should be 0 because red car doesn't equal total row count of table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT ISNULL(b.numrows, 0) as numrows
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM car
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM car WHERE redcar = 'yes'
) b ON b.numrows = a.numrows
```

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way I can think of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.car
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CAR where COALESCE(redcar, '') <> 'yes')
```

Since you want to return all rows, this just checks if any rows don't meet your condition, and if so it should return 0 or nothing.

Comment: This says: for each row, check if there's any non-red car.  Then count the number of matching rows.  Without a query optimizer, this would do one table scan for each row, or an O(N^2) algorithm.

Comment: @Andomar - it's not correlated so it will only run the check once.

Comment: +1 noting the spec originally read, "only select count value if total row count is equal to row count with special ID" which immediately suggests looking for non matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` to return `0` if the matched row count is different from the total number of rows:

```
SELECT  case when count(*) = (select count(*) from dbo.car) then count(*)
        else 0
        end
FROM    dbo.car 
WHERE   redcar = 'yes'
```

This will return one row with `0` if the condition is not met. The `if` statement would return no rowset at all. You might have to adjust the client code to account for this.

Comment: it runs without error but i just get total max rows even if redcars total doesn't equal total max row count of table. I just posted a diagram of the table.

Comment: @user719825 - did you try my query yet?

Comment: @user719825: Query edited so it returns 0 if the rowcount doesn't match

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM dbo.car
HAVING count(*) = sum (Case When redcar = 'yes' Then 1 Else 0 End)
```

or this:

```
SELECT allcars
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) redcars FROM dbo.car WHERE redcar = 'yes') as redcars
  cross join (SELECT COUNT(*) allcars FROM dbo.car) as allcars
 WHERE redcars = allcars
```

But why do you want one query? Doing with variables like your code is much more easy to read.

Comment: it runs without error but i just get total max rows even if redcars total doesn't equal total max row count of table. I just posted a diagram of the table.